# Expo managed android - how can I include firebase for a managed expo app?

Tags: firebase, react-native, push-notification, expo, firebase-cloud-messaging

When using push notifications, I must include firebase for android, even if I otherwise dont use firebase. I have been following the instructions on expo and firebase but dont understand the following: I have a managed expo app so how can I add the native code as the following, instructed on firebase:

[image]

What is the way to do it on a managed expo app? Thanks!

Comment: Follow this instructions https://docs.expo.dev/push-notifications/push-notifications-setup/